# Adding a collation to postgresql if it does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, collation

I want to add a collation to postgresql DB only if the collation does not exists

How can I check for the existing collation in postgesql 9.1.* ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Depends on used operation system. First you have to have support for required collation by locales on O.S. You can check it on linux with command `locale -a`. If you find there requested locale, you can register it by statement `CREATE COLLATION` (example from [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createcollation.html))

```
CREATE COLLATION french (LOCALE = 'fr_FR.utf8');
```

You can get list of available collations by `\dOS` or with select:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_collation;
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the OS, question is about if the collation is in the  DB not the OS. The second part might be helpful though ! thanks

Comment: @JoErlang: Postgres uses system libraries for collation implementation, so you cannot to add any collation without related support in OS